# JSDoc single file Vue components

Tags: vue.js, jsdoc

I'm trying to run JSDoc on my single file Vue components. I've found two plugins that sound like they should work (both seem to be based on the same code in fact):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-doc

and

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc-vue

The plugin breaks when shorthand is used, but that's not a big issue, I can just use longhand. However every single file component I try to run JSDoc on gets this error:

> Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

This implies that my component doesn't have a single root element, but they all do. I set up a test component like so, but it fails:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    {{someData}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        someData: "Test Data"
      }
    },
    methods: {
      /**
       * Just a test function
       * @function
       */
      testFunction: function () {
        alert("Testing")
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="stylus">
  div {
    border: 1px solid;
  }
</style>
```

Does anyone have any experience with running JSDoc on .vue files? It seems like it should be possible, but there's very little info online.

Thanks

Comment: Did you set up your conf.json?

Comment: We are using this handy doc generator. Maybe it's something for you. https://github.com/vue-styleguidist/vue-styleguidist

Comment: As of 2020, jsdoc-vue does not has the problems reported by the OP and it's quite simple to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been using [documentation.js](https://documentation.js.org/) to document my Vue files. [Here's an excellent article](https://medium.com/4thought-studios/documenting-javascript-projects-f72429da2eea) on how to get started using it. I've been very impressed with how easy it is to use, and it generates good looking HTML files that you can use to easily search for the functions you've written.

For example, if you create a Vue file like this:

```html
<template>
    <div>{{mydata}}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            mydata: "hello"
        }
    },
    methods: {
        /**
         * Add two numbers.
         * @param{number} num1 The first number to add
         * @param{number} num2 The second number to add
         * @return{number} The sum of the two numbers.
         */
        addnums: function(num1, num2) {
            return num1 + num2;
        },

        /**
         * Concatenate two strings.
         * @param{string} str1 The first string to concatenate.
         * @param{string} str2 The second string to concatenate.
         * @return{string} The concatentation of the two strings.
         */
        concat: function(str1, str2) {
            return str1 + str2;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Running `documentation build /path/to/file.vue -f html -o docs` will create a beautiful HTML file that looks like this in the browser:

[image]

**2019 EDIT:**

I actually found a new library yesterday called [vuese](https://github.com/vue-contrib/vuese) that was built specifically for documenting Vue components. While documentation.js will do a great job of helping you document your methods, vuese takes it a step further by letting you add documentation to your props and components. It's incredibly easy to use.

I pretty much learned everything I needed to know from [this blog post](https://dev.to/berniwittmann/quick--easy-documentation-generation-for-vuejs-components-7k6).

Comment: Great! But I have a trouble with pug( 
Error: Parsing file /path/to/file.vue: Unexpected token (1:0)

My file.vue start with <template lang="pug">
Can you help me?

Comment: @DmytroLishtvan Hmm...I haven't played around with Pug too much and not at all using Vue. My guess is that documentation.js was built specifically for parsing HTML/JS files, someone please correct me if I'm wrong. Check out my edit above regarding vuese, I'm guessing it should probably play nicely with Pug templates.

Comment: @Brett Fisher Hi there! I'm not having much luck using vuese-parser to modify the documents produced by vuese.  Mostly, I'm just looking to add a "returns" column for my methods.  Any chance you can point me in the right direction or provide an example?

Comment: Just a note that after `vuese gen ` you should run `vuese serve --open` - instead, you will see a constantly loading page when you open index.html

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple @component plugin which helps to parse .vue files with @jsdoc. It also generates preview for them. Check it out: https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/better-docs